# what is the render of Size object?

Tags: flutter, dart

i need to create a context for PreferredSize with an specific size, the question is why the return height value is coming from the container height with regardless  `Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(100);`?

**the scaffold code is:**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen();
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:  const _AppBar(), //the cursor is here
    );
  }
```

**the _AppBar class is:**

```
class _AppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  const _AppBar();
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(100);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Color(0xFF257863),
      child: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.18,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Because the container height property overrides preferredSize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preferredSize` is used by some parent widgets to set the maximum constraints of the inner widget.

The inner widget's size does not have to fill these constraints, though - size is determined by the inner widget itself.

For more information on constraints and size, take a look at [Understanding constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints) in the Flutter documentation.